# How to remove Google Copyright on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to remove on google maps placed on my website the Google Adv (on the right-bottom of each map) :

```
Map Data 2011 Google PPWK ...
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

**Edit:** (copy content from comment)
The relevant piece of the linked page is as follows, in case the page becomes unavailable:

FAQ #1:

> **Can you give me permission to show your content without
>   attribution, or put the attribution at the end of my book/movie/TV
>   show?**
>
> Without exception, we require attribution when Content
>   is shown. If you are unwilling to meet our attribution requirements,
>   please contact our data provider(s) directly to inquire about
>   purchasing the rights to the content directly.

Answer (score 21):

Use CSS for to remove "Google logo" and "terms of use" from google maps use this

To remove "terms of use" use this CSS

```
.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
```

To remove Google logo use this css

```
img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white2.png"], a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Note:- This answer is for only learning purpose it is advised do not remove Google logo in commercial projects.

Comment: WARNING: this is a violation of Google's ToS

Comment: @knitevision - Be realistic.  You are more likely to have your site blocked from accessing the API, your app dropped from the appstore, or receive a "cease and desist" letter in the mail.

Answer (score 13):

Pay for the [commercial version](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps_features.html) of the map data and then ask Google.

Comment: I don't believe Google removes the attribution for paying customers either.

Comment: If you pay them enough they will :-)

Comment: @StephenC by enough you mean billions? :D

Comment: @peter - something like that.

Answer (score 8):

If you go through the questions on the Permissions page, you'll eventually be presented with the following rules regarding attribution:

http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1342531

> All uses of Google Maps and Google Earth and its Content must provide
>   attribution to Google and our suppliers. Google does not approve of
>   any use of Content without proper attribution. Depending on the
>   region, the Content provider may be Google alone or Google and one or
>   more 3rd party providers.
>
> Requirements:
>
> Attribute Google (e.g. © 2011 Google) and third-party suppliers (e.g.
>   © 2011 Tele Atlas) Make attribution readable to the average reader or
>   viewer (e.g. avoid micro-sized letters) For Print: Display attribution
>   within or immediately adjacent to the visual For Online: Attribution
>   is automatically added within the API and cannot not obscured. For
>   TV/Video: Display attribution the entire duration the Content is
>   shown, only showing attribution briefly at the start, end, or credits
>   is not allowed Where to Find the Attribution: Attribution is in the
>   bottom right of Google Maps and in the bottom center of Google Earth
>   Please note suppliers of Content can change between zoom levels as
>   well as among regions
>
> Additional Information:
>
> Attribution is in the bottom right of Google Maps and in the bottom
>   center of Google Earth For screenshots, the Google or or Google Maps
>   logo is not required but attribution must always be present. However,
>   the reverse is not allowed - only including Google logo is not proper
>   attribution, particularly when 3rd-party suppliers were used for the
>   Content. Google logos cannot be used in-line (e.g. "These maps from
>   [Google logo].")

Answer (score 6):

simply code css for logo

```
img[src=http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white2.png]
{display:none}
```

or use this code

img tag into a tag

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}
```

Comment: This:

a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}

Works like a charm with the v3 on PhoneGap.

Thanks!

Comment: WARNING: this is a violation of Google's ToS

Comment: thanks Stephen C, this answer just a solution for hide google logo, i do not like violation of copyright

Comment: Read this: https://www.google.com.au/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html.  OK, so providing a technical solution probably isn't a violation of the ToS.  But anyone who does what you are suggesting >>is<< violating the ToS.  And since that means they don't have permission to use the Map APIs, there is a good chance that they are violating copyright *as a consequence*.

Answer (score 4):

you just need to hide the banner div.
Add this to your css.  use firebug to get the div class or id and hide it.

e.g

```
.olLayerGooglePoweredBy

{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Combining all of the above answers, this CSS worked for me.

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}

.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
```

Comment: WARNING: this is a violation of Google's ToS

Comment: @StephenC - dude, get life!

Answer (score 3):

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}
a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}

.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span, .gm-style-cc {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
```

this work like a charm

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?