# Google static maps API with no labels?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am using Google static maps to get a image (to display in a ImageView) in Android. Here is how I get the Image:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+york,NY&zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7CNew+york,NY
```

Which generates this image:

[image]

However, I want to get rid of the *"Google"* and *"Map data @2016 Google"*, and also places like *"Brookfield Place"* and *"New York Stock Exchange"*.

You can remove all labels with `style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off` like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+york,NY&zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7CNew+york,NY&format=png&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off
```

But that removes everything except the labels at bottom of the photo.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I found out how to get rid of so called "Point of interest(s)" but the two bottom labels are still there.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+york,NY&zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7CNew+york,NY&format=png&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off
```

[image]

Is it even possible to remove them?

Comment: Try `feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off`..check https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+york,NY&zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7CNew+york,NY&format=png&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off

Comment: @Lal Thanks, I just found out about that on their website and tried, but Is it possible to remove "Google" and "Maos data (at)2016 Google" ?

Comment: No way..check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652591/how-to-remove-google-copyright-on-google-maps)

Comment: Removing those marks violates the Google Maps API Terms of Service (Section 8.4.b.viii) https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: @Lal Oh ok I see, thanks. You can "answer" with your comment if you would want me to thumbs up&accept your answer since it was the exact thing I was looking for

Comment: No, Google protect its own

Comment: @antonio Oh ok thanks!

Comment: @Selvin Yeah Ill have to let it stay then! Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off
```

Check this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=New+york,NY&zoom=13&size=300x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7CNew+york,NY&format=png&style=feature:poi|element:labels|visibility:off

[image]

Comment: Thankyou..@Carlton

Comment: hi you did a great effort but i wants to do draw marker for the current place and get its static image view, kindly help me